# Wordpress : Add_cap || edit menu only

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

*(first, sorry for my poor english)*

I'm wondering if there is a pure php way to allow an **editor user** to edit the menu.

This code allow the **editor** to access the **appearance** menu and it works fine.

```
// get the the role object
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );

// add capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

But I **don't want him to edit the theme** or widget. I know there are plugins to manage those capabilities but I'm looking for a plain php way to do this, any ideas?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this?

```
$role_object = get_role('editor');
$role_object->add_cap('edit_theme_options');

add_action('admin_head', function() 
{
  // Check if the user === 'editor'
  if (is_object(get_role('editor'))) {
      remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'themes.php');
      remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'widgets.php');
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about `remove_submenu_page` ! Helps a lot indeed, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm kinda new to wordpress :)

Comment: @AlexisWollseifen Glad it is working now! Don't forget to set your question to resolve.